# Accessing external git repo from my Gitlab pipeline

Tags: git, gitlab-ci

I am trying to access a different git repo from my pipeline. But I am getting this error. Can someone please help.

```
prepare-3.7:
  stage: build
  script:
    - apt-get install -y git
    - git clone https://main.gitlab.in.company.com/parent/repo.git
```

Current output -

Cloning into 'repo'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://main.gitlab.in.company.com': No such device or address

Comment: try `git clone https://the_auth_token_you_generated_in_main_gitlab_in_company_com@github.com/parent/repo.git`

Comment: I tried this. But getting error-  git clone https://<token>@main.gitlab.in.company.com/parent/repo.git
Cloning into 'repo'...
/bin/bash: /git_creds.sh: No such file or directory
Password : 
/bin/bash: /git_creds.sh: No such file or directory
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed

Comment: i suspect your gitlab runner is not well configured. suggest try using some official *git* image in this job.